# Extracting and aggregating data out of filenames in python or pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have these four lists, which are the filenames of images and the filenames are in the format:

(disease)-(randomized patient ID)-(image number by this patient)

A single patient can have multiple images per disease.

See these slices below:

```
print(train_cnv_list[0:3])
print(train_dme_list[0:3])
print(train_drusen_list[0:3])
print(train_normal_list[0:3])
>>>
['CNV-9911627-77.jpeg', 'CNV-9935363-45.jpeg', 'CNV-9911627-94.jpeg']
['DME-8889850-2.jpeg', 'DME-8773471-3.jpeg', 'DME-8797076-11.jpeg']
['DRUSEN-8986660-50.jpeg', 'DRUSEN-9100857-3.jpeg', 'DRUSEN-9025088-5.jpeg']
['NORMAL-9490249-31.jpeg', 'NORMAL-9509694-5.jpeg', 'NORMAL-9504376-3.jpeg']
```

I'd like to figure out:

1. How many images are there per patient / per list?
2. Is there any overlap in the "randomized patient ID" across the four lists? If so, can I aggregate that into some kind of report (patient, disease, number of images) using something like groupby?

```
patient - disease1 - total number of images

        - disease2 - total number of images

        - disease3 - total number of images
```

where total number of images is a max(image number by this patient)

I did see that this yields a patient id:

```
train_cnv_list[0][4:11]
>>> 9911627
```

Thanks, in advance, for any guidance.

Comment: IMHO a bit too broad. Look into the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function to get the separate components of the file names, then use dictionaries for counting.

Comment: For #2, when you say overlap, are you trying to check for duplicates?

Comment: This problem is a great opportunity to learn the pandas library. It's exactly what you want to do this.

Comment: @KyleDixon Yes, I want to see if patients have multiple disorders - so does their id show up across the four lists? I'm going to edit the question to add more detail on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few functions that might get you on the right track, but as @rick-supports-monica mentioned, this is a great use case for pandas. You'll have an easier time manipulating data.

```py
def contains_duplicate_ids(img_list):
  patient_ids = []
  for image in img_list:
    patient_id = image.split('.')[0].split('-')[1]
    patient_ids.append(patient_id)

  if len(set(patient_ids)) == len(patient_ids):
    return False
  
  return True

def get_duplicates(img_list):
  patient_ids = []
  duplicates = []

  for image in img_list:
    patient_id = image.split('.')[0].split('-')[1]

    if patient_id in patient_ids:
      duplicates.append(patient_id)

    patient_ids.append(patient_id)

  return duplicates

def count_images(img_list):
  return len(set(img_list))
```

From `get_duplicates` you can use the patient IDs returned to lookup whatever you want from there. I'm not sure I completely understand the structure of the lists. It looks like `{disease}-{patient_id}-{some_other_int}.jpg`. I'm not sure how to add additional lookups to the functionality without understanding the input a bit more.

I mentioned pandas, but didn't mention how to use it, here's one way you could get your existing data into a dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
train_cnv_list = ['CNV-9911627-77.jpeg', 'CNV-9935363-45.jpeg', 'CNV-9911628-94.jpeg', 'CNM-9911629-94.jpeg']
train_dme_list = ['DME-8889850-2.jpeg', 'DME-8773471-3.jpeg', 'DME-8797076-11.jpeg']
train_drusen_list = ['DRUSEN-8986660-50.jpeg', 'DRUSEN-9100857-3.jpeg', 'DRUSEN-9025088-5.jpeg']
train_normal_list = ['NORMAL-9490249-31.jpeg', 'NORMAL-9509694-5.jpeg', 'NORMAL-9504376-3.jpeg']

# Convert list to dataframe
def dataframe_from_list(img_list):
  df = pd.DataFrame(img_list, columns=['filename'])

  df['disease'] = [filename.split('.')[0].split('-')[0] for filename in img_list]
  df['patient_id'] = [filename.split('.')[0].split('-')[1] for filename in img_list]
  df['some_other_int'] = [filename.split('.')[0].split('-')[2] for filename in img_list]

  return df

# Generate a dataframe for each list
cnv_df = dataframe_from_list(train_cnv_list)
dme_df = dataframe_from_list(train_dme_list)
drusen_df = dataframe_from_list(train_drusen_list)
normal_df = dataframe_from_list(train_normal_list)

# or combine them into one long dataframe
df = pd.concat([cnv_df, dme_df, drusen_df, normal_df], ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

cnv_list=['CNV-9911627-77.jpeg', 'CNV-9935363-45.jpeg', 'CNV-9911627-94.jpeg']
dme_list=['DME-8889850-2.jpeg', 'DME-8773471-3.jpeg', 'DME-8797076-11.jpeg']
dru_list=['DRUSEN-8986660-50.jpeg', 'DRUSEN-9100857-3.jpeg', 'DRUSEN-9025088-5.jpeg']
nor_list=['NORMAL-9490249-31.jpeg', 'NORMAL-9509694-5.jpeg', 'NORMAL-9504376-3.jpeg']

data =[]
data.extend(cnv_list)
data.extend(dme_list)
data.extend(dru_list)
data.extend(nor_list)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["files"])
df["files"]=df["files"].str.replace ('.jpeg','')
df=df["files"].str.split('-', expand=True).rename(columns={0:"disease",1:"PatientID",2:"pictureName"})
res = df.groupby(['PatientID','disease']).apply(lambda x: x['pictureName'].count())
print(res)
```

Result:

```
PatientID  disease
8773471    DME        1
8797076    DME        1
8889850    DME        1
8986660    DRUSEN     1
9025088    DRUSEN     1
9100857    DRUSEN     1
9490249    NORMAL     1
9504376    NORMAL     1
9509694    NORMAL     1
9911627    CNV        2
9935363    CNV        1
```

and even more now than you have a dataFrame...

Comment: This great. What I noticed, when I checked the actual folders with the image files, is that that your final 'res' df is counting exactly half of the actual images (because there are repeats of the exact filenames!). I looked up the .count() method in pandas and it looks like it would count repeat filenames, so I'm a bit confused why it's showing only half the count...

Comment: I did .astype(int) on 'pictureName' and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Start by creating a well defined data structure, use counter in order to answer your first question.

```
from typing import NamedTuple
from collections import Counter,defaultdict

class FileInfo(NamedTuple):
  disease:str
  patient_id:str
  image_id: str


l1 = ['CNV-9911627-77.jpeg', 'CNV-9935363-45.jpeg', 'CNV-9911627-94.jpeg']
l2 = ['DME-8889850-2.jpeg', 'DME-8773471-3.jpeg', 'DME-8797076-11.jpeg']
l3 = ['DRUSEN-8986660-50.jpeg', 'DRUSEN-9100857-3.jpeg', 'DRUSEN-9025088-5.jpeg']
l4 = ['NORMAL-9490249-31.jpeg', 'NORMAL-9509694-5.jpeg', 'NORMAL-9504376-3.jpeg']
lists = [l1,l2,l3,l4]
data_lists = []
for l in lists:
  data_lists.append([FileInfo(*f[:-5].split('-')) for f in l])
counters = []
for l in data_lists:
  counters.append(Counter(fi.patient_id for fi in l))
print(counters)
print('-----------')
cross_lists_data = dict()
for l in data_lists:
  for file_info in l:
    if file_info.patient_id not in cross_lists_data:
      cross_lists_data[file_info.patient_id] =  defaultdict(int)
    cross_lists_data[file_info.patient_id][file_info.disease] += 1  
print(cross_lists_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by concatenating your data

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

train_cnv_list = ['CNV-9911627-77.jpeg', 'CNV-9935363-45.jpeg', 'CNV-9911627-94.jpeg']
train_dme_list = ['DME-8889850-2.jpeg', 'DME-8773471-3.jpeg', 'DME-8797076-11.jpeg']
train_drusen_list = ['DRUSEN-8986660-50.jpeg', 'DRUSEN-9100857-3.jpeg', 'DRUSEN-9025088-5.jpeg']
train_normal_list = ['NORMAL-9490249-31.jpeg', 'NORMAL-9509694-5.jpeg', 'NORMAL-9504376-3.jpeg']

train_data = np.array([
    train_cnv_list, 
    train_dme_list,
    train_drusen_list,
    train_normal_list
])
```

Create a Series with the flattened array

```
>>> train = pd.Series(train_data.flat)
>>> train

0        CNV-9911627-77.jpeg
1        CNV-9935363-45.jpeg
2        CNV-9911627-94.jpeg
3         DME-8889850-2.jpeg
4         DME-8773471-3.jpeg
5        DME-8797076-11.jpeg
6     DRUSEN-8986660-50.jpeg
7      DRUSEN-9100857-3.jpeg
8      DRUSEN-9025088-5.jpeg
9     NORMAL-9490249-31.jpeg
10     NORMAL-9509694-5.jpeg
11     NORMAL-9504376-3.jpeg
dtype: object
```

Use `Series.str.extract` together with regex to extract the information from the filenames and separate it into different columns

```
>>> pat = '(?P<Disease>\w+)-(?P<Patient_ID>\d+)-(?P<IMG_ID>\d+).jpeg'
>>> train = train.str.extract(pat)
>>> train

   Disease Patient_ID IMG_ID
0      CNV    9911627     77
1      CNV    9935363     45
2      CNV    9911627     94
3      DME    8889850      2
4      DME    8773471      3
5      DME    8797076     11
6   DRUSEN    8986660     50
7   DRUSEN    9100857      3
8   DRUSEN    9025088      5
9   NORMAL    9490249     31
10  NORMAL    9509694      5
11  NORMAL    9504376      3
```

Finally, aggregate the data and compute the total number of images per group based on the maximum `IMG_ID` number.

```
>>> report = train.groupby(["Patient_ID","Disease"])['IMG_ID'].agg(Total_IMGs="max")
>>> report

                   Total_IMGs
Patient_ID Disease           
8773471    DME              3
8797076    DME             11
8889850    DME              2
8986660    DRUSEN          50
9025088    DRUSEN           5
9100857    DRUSEN           3
9490249    NORMAL          31
9504376    NORMAL           3
9509694    NORMAL           5
9911627    CNV             94
9935363    CNV             45
```